# Build interval then calculate the maximum number of Disjoint Intervals

Tags: r, intervals

I want to know the maximum number of flight on the ground by station .

I have time when the flight arrive to the station and depart from the station.

the problem that my data frame is in this format

```
  REG DEP ARV  STD                    STA
  XYZ ZRH GVA  2021-08-01 07:20:00    2021-08-01 08:35:00
  XYZ GVA ZRH  2021-08-01 09:20:00    2021-08-01 10:35:00
  KLN MUC GVA  2021-08-01 06:00:00    2021-08-01 07:10:00
  KLN GVA CGD  2021-08-01 08:45:00    2021-08-01 10:10:00
```

So in this example
flight **XYZ** arrive in GVA AT 08H35 (first line STA) and then depart from GVA AT 09H20( LINE 2 STD) and
flight **KLN** arrive to GVA AT 07H10 and depart AT 08H45.
so from 08h35 to 08h45 there is 2 flight in GVA..

the output should be 2 if for this day there is only this two flight who meet in GVA.

if in other time in the day there other flight who meet suppose there is 5 flights in the afternoon who meet in GVA.
so the output should be the maximum it mean **5**.

so I was thinking to build interval by flight [STA, STD] or [STD,STA] then find Maximal Disjoint Intervals...

I tried this code to builds the interval but is not working..

```
interval_sta_std<-function(i,j){
for (i in 1:length(df)){
  key=  df$DEP[i]
  min_key=min(df$STD[i])
  max_key=max(df$STD[i])

 
 for (j in 1:length(df)){
   value=  df$ARV[j]
   min_value=min(df$STA[j])
   max_value=max(df$STA[j])
 
 if(value==key) {
   
   
test_inter<-interval(min(min_value,min_key),
                    max(max_key,max_value))
 }
 }
 }
   return(test_inter)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one way is to look at after minute during your data and count how many flights are on deck for that minute. This doesn't always scale well depending on the breadth of your data, but if you limit `minutes` to a reasonable scope, then it should be fine.

### Sample data

```r
quux <- structure(list(REG = c("XYZ", "XYZ", "KLN", "KLN"), DEP = c("ZRH", "GVA", "MUC", "GVA"), ARV = c("GVA", "ZRH", "GVA", "CGD"), STD = structure(c(1627816800, 1627824000, 1627812000, 1627821900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), STA = structure(c(1627821300, 1627828500, 1627816200, 1627827000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
quux[,c("STD","STA")] <- lapply(quux[,c("STD","STA")], as.POSIXct)
```

(Converting your `STD` and `STA` to `POSIXt` objects.)

### base R with fuzzyjoin

```r
minutes <- seq(min(quux$STD), max(quux$STA), by = "mins")
head(minutes)
# [1] "2021-08-01 06:00:00 EDT" "2021-08-01 06:01:00 EDT" "2021-08-01 06:02:00 EDT" "2021-08-01 06:03:00 EDT"
# [5] "2021-08-01 06:04:00 EDT" "2021-08-01 06:05:00 EDT"
length(minutes)
# [1] 276
range(minutes)
# [1] "2021-08-01 06:00:00 EDT" "2021-08-01 10:35:00 EDT"
```

Now the join and aggregation.

```r
joined <- fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(data.frame(M = minutes), quux, by = c("M" = "STD", "M" = "STA"), match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`))
head(joined)
#                     M REG DEP ARV                 STD                 STA
# 1 2021-08-01 06:00:00 KLN MUC GVA 2021-08-01 06:00:00 2021-08-01 07:10:00
# 2 2021-08-01 06:01:00 KLN MUC GVA 2021-08-01 06:00:00 2021-08-01 07:10:00
# 3 2021-08-01 06:02:00 KLN MUC GVA 2021-08-01 06:00:00 2021-08-01 07:10:00
# 4 2021-08-01 06:03:00 KLN MUC GVA 2021-08-01 06:00:00 2021-08-01 07:10:00
# 5 2021-08-01 06:04:00 KLN MUC GVA 2021-08-01 06:00:00 2021-08-01 07:10:00
# 6 2021-08-01 06:05:00 KLN MUC GVA 2021-08-01 06:00:00 2021-08-01 07:10:00
nrow(joined)
# [1] 327
```

Recall that we had `276` in `minutes`. Now we have 327, indicating that 51 rows (each minute) indicate more than one flight on deck at a time.

```r
joined2 <- aggregate(REG ~ M, data = joined[complete.cases(joined),], FUN = length)
nrow(joined2)
# [1] 258
head(joined2)
#                     M REG
# 1 2021-08-01 06:00:00   1
# 2 2021-08-01 06:01:00   1
# 3 2021-08-01 06:02:00   1
# 4 2021-08-01 06:03:00   1
# 5 2021-08-01 06:04:00   1
# 6 2021-08-01 06:05:00   1
```

We've reduced a bit, indicating that 258 minutes during the day(s) in the data had at least one plane on deck; if you look at where `REG > 1`, you'll find where there are two or more.

The final piece:

```r
joined2$Date <- as.Date(joined2$M)
aggregate(REG ~ Date, data = joined2, FUN = max)
#         Date REG
# 1 2021-08-01   2
```

Note: this might be subject to time zone issues, ensure you're confident they are all correct.

Comment: thank you @r2evans  for you answer, Your solution seems perfect to me, but I would like the output to be per station. in MUC , max = 2 , in GVA, max= 5...
my database is huge ( from 2021 to 2022) by day ( 557860 obs) , When I try to apply your solution using my database i get this error:  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 358.7 Gb

Comment: You can work in specific grouping for each of `DEP` and `ARV`, but your memory issue suggests you have a lot of data, this is somewhat critical to the problem and should be clearly stated in the question.

Comment: Hello @r2vans, I was re-applying your code using a loop for each DEP and ARV, but then I discovered that you are matching the minutes with STA and STD by line and not by  REG. for example in the first DEP From MUC at 06:00:00 and ARV  to GVA at   07:10:00. this is what the DF propose but what we realy need is the time that the flight is in the ground by station. it mean here in GVA the fligt arrive at 07:10 and then DEP from GVA AT 08:45 (the next line using always reg :KLN)
so our intrval become [ 07:10, 08:45] and not [ 06:00; 07:10].

Comment: @r2vans,There is any idea how to creat this intravl , it depend the case (REG, STA [i], STD[i])  or  (REG, STD [i], STD[i])    and then mattching with the mintues as you didi??

Comment: I see, right, should have known that already ...